# Combining two Observable<Void>s

Tags: swift, reactive-programming, rx-swift

I'm still a reactive newbie and I'm looking for help.

```
func doA() -> Observable<Void>
func doB() -> Observable<Void>

enum Result {
    case Success
    case BFailed
}

func doIt() -> Observable<Result> {

    // start both doA and doB. 
    // If both complete then emit .Success and complete
    // If doA completes, but doB errors emit .BFailed and complete
    // If both error then error

}
```

The above is what I think I want... The initial functions `doA()` and `doB()` wrap network calls so they will both emit one signal and then `Complete` (or `Error` without emitting any `Next` events.) If `doA()` completes but `doB()` errors, I want `doIt()` to emit `.BFailed` and then complete.

It feels like I should be using `zip` or `combineLatest` but I'm not sure how to know which sequence failed if I do that. I'm also pretty sure that `catchError` is part of the solution, but I'm not sure exactly where to put it.

--

As I'm thinking about it, I'm okay with the calls happening sequentially. That might even be better...

IE:

```
Start doA() 
    if it completes start doB() 
        if it completes emit .Success 
        else emit .BFailed.
    else forward the error.
```

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've learned RxSwift well enough to answer this question now...

```
func doIt() -> Observable<Result> {
    Observable.zip(
        doA().map { Result.Success },
        doB().map { Result.Success }
            .catch { _ in Observable.just(Result.BFailed) }
    ) { $1 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe `.flatMapLatest()` is what you're looking for, chaining your observable requests.

```
doFirst()
.flatMapLatest({ [weak self] (firstResult) -> Observable<Result> in
  // Assuming this doesn't fail and returns result on main scheduler,
  // otherwise `catchError` and `observeOn(MainScheduler.instance)` can be used to correct this
  // ...
  // do something with result #1
  // ...
  return self?.doSecond()
}).subscribeNext { [weak self] (secondResult) -> Void in
  // ...
  // do something with result #2
  // ...
}.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

And here is `.flatMapLatest()` doc in RxSwift.

> Projects each element of an observable sequence into a new sequence of observable sequences and then
>            transforms an observable sequence of observable sequences into an observable sequence producing values only from the most recent observable sequence. It is a combination of `map` + `switchLatest` operator.

Answer (score 0):

I apologize that I don't know the syntax for swift, so I'm writing the answer in c#. The code should be directly translatable.

```
var query =
    doA
        .Materialize()
        .Zip(doB.Materialize(), (ma, mb) => new { ma, mb })
        .Select(x =>
            x.ma.Kind == NotificationKind.OnError
            || x.mb.Kind == NotificationKind.OnError
                ? Result.BFailed
                : Result.Success);
```

Basically the `.Materialize()` operator turns the `OnNext`, `OnError`, and `OnCompleted` notifications for an observable of type `T` into `OnNext` notifications for an observable of type `Notification<T>`. You can then `.Zip(...)` these and check for your required conditions.

Comment: Hmm... Thanks for the answer, but RxSwift does not have the materialize method. At least not yet.